# PEAR Dont see XML_Parser

Tags: php, xml, pear

I install XML/RSS package from PRAR. And i see it

```
ls -la /usr/share/php/XML/
итого 84
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 авг  8 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root  4096 авг  8 14:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 авг  5 11:49 Parser
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 20928 авг  8 14:19 Parser.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 авг  8 13:32 RPC2
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 10457 авг  8 14:04 RSS.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 30531 авг  8 14:08 Util.php
```

But when i try to use RSS parser i have error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PEAR::XML_Parser() in /usr/share/php/PEAR.php on line 218" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.1, server: www.example.org, request: "GET /team/cron HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "example.org"
```

Comment: which pear version, which xml_parser version?